# Why can't a range object be used to index a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, slice

In Python 3.9, it is not possible to use a range object to index a list.
Indeed running the following code, the second print will return an error stating "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not range".

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
s = slice(3)
r = range(3)

print(x[s]) # ok
print(x[r]) # error
```

Why is this? Couldn't the Python interpreter just convert the range to a slice under the hood, and use that for indexing?
Is this because of some fundamental reason, or is just something the developer did not implement (yet?)?

Interestingly, it is indeed possible to index numpy arrays using range!

Comment: Note that ``numpy`` does *not* use ``range``s as ``slice``s. Compare ``np.array([1, 2, 3])[range(0, -2)]`` and ``np.array([1, 2, 3])[slice(0, -2)]``. Numpy uses the ``range`` for what it is – a sequence.

Comment: The conversion is indeed trivial (`slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)`), but I can't think of a practical situation where you have one but want the other.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, thank you, very interesting example: the meaning of negative numbers in slice helps me understand why range cannot serve the same function (i.e. indexing lists) as slice. If you want to make your comment an answer I would be happy to accept it.
chepner, thank you, I knew about that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `slice` and `range` are subtly different things, even though both use a `start, stop, step` triplet. If Python were to silently use one in place of the other, it could lead to subtle bugs.

---

To see the difference directly, one can indeed look at `numpy` where the two cause different indexing:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr[slice(1, -1)]
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr[range(1, -1)]
array([], dtype=int64)
```

The result is different because `slice` and `range` have different meaning for negative numbers.

- A `range` represents a part of the [number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line) of integers. This extends to negative numbers.
- A `slice` represents a part of the [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)/indices of sequences.<sup>1</sup> This wraps negative numbers back to positive numbers.

Or put simpler, the meaning of a `slice` depends on the size of a sequence whereas a `range` does not. Thus, accidentally using one in place of the other would be wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, a `slice` represents *any* concept of `start, stop, step`. The standard sequence types interpret this as numerical indices. It is also possible for a `slice` to represent the *edges* of a graph, for example.